# Remove scrolling lag with UIScrollView with dynamically rendered items

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, uikit

I have a set of items with images, videos and .gif images that are displayed in a UIWebView that are being rendered dynamically when user scrolls to the bottom of the scree and reaches the end of the current UIScrollView offset. When downloading the items from the web I can display an activity indicator that makes user experience smooth and nice, but when I have all the data cached and retrieve it from cache I have a pretty annoying lag when all the items are being rendered at the same time (5 items per loading operation). My question is: **Is it possible to somehow remove the lag from the UIScrollView when rendering items on it? And how can I display an activity indicator when rendering items on main thread?** Specifically the lag happens when user scrolls to bottom, the scroll freezes, all items are rendered and scroll continues to go to bottom with the same force user has dragged it with.

P.S. I cannot use UITableView, so please do not suggest using it instead of scroll view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using NINetworkImageView from the Nimbus project: https://github.com/jverkoey/nimbus

The reason it works well in your scenario is because it's manipulating the fetched image on a different thread. It does things like cropping and resizing and just gives you the end result on the main thread.

For a more complete sample, please see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10361005/434841 for a similar question.

Comment: I'm downloading images on a separate thread. The question is not about how to download images on the background thread, it's about how to remove the lag from UIScrollView while simultaneously scrolling and rendering items and if that's possible at all. Thanks anyway

Comment: It's a bit hard to decipher what the problem is, one of the common mistakes is using a big picture and letting the UIImageView to render it smaller. Please post your code so I can take a look. Did you try using Nimbus for that scenario?

Comment: Hello Yosi, thanks for your concern. I'm downloading images, resizing them into smaller images and use the resized versions, so there's no issue here. My problem was that the UI froze, I fixed the problem by drawing an activity indicator and asking users to wait... still I'll mark your answer as correct, thanks

Comment: Eugene, it means you're blocking the main thread which is something you should always avoid - you should be able to give the user the ability to cancel a long running process and if you block the main thread the click would not register.